# Visual studio code c++ indent

Tags: visual-studio, editor, indentation, auto-indent

I want to use Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio C++,
but what bothers me is that auto indent.

I want Visual Studio Code to auto indent like Visual Studio C++. See the difference in below images

Visual Studio Code

[image: visual code]

Visual Studio C++

[image: visual c++]

How to modify VS Code settings to works like VSC++?
Please help!